# How can I make smaller pop-ups on Lubuntu?

Tags: configuration, lubuntu, notify-osd

I want to see smaller pop-ups but where have I to go to configure this?

[image: For example, when power manager pops up: I want a smaller notification]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the OS version, one may have to to replace the existing Lubuntu notify pop-up with the XFCE equivalent:

XFCE Popup
[image]

Lubuntu Popup
[image]

It has a simple config GUI (`xfce4-notifyd-config`) - by default the notification size is smaller - similar to the Unity pop-ups.

[image]

Since all the desktop popups work with the same underlying libnotify - using the XFCE variant in Lubuntu is fully compatible.

**to install**

Install the XFCE Notify Pop-up if you don't see it in your list of installed software (`dpkg --get-selections | grep "xfce4-notify"`):

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-notifyd
```

---

#### 11.10 users

It doesn't work with `notify-osd` if you have this also installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove notify-osd
```

Logout and login for the changes to take effect.

#### 12.04 users

You need to remove `notification-daemon` as described using this Q&A:

- [How can I make xfce4-volumed keep giving notifications in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166194/how-can-i-make-xfce4-volumed-keep-giving-notifications-in-lubuntu)

#### 12.10 users

> Notification-daemon have been replaced for xfce4-notifyd on the default installation

In other words, [it's the default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu). You don't have to install or uninstall anything and the notifications are already smaller. But you can still do useful things such as choose

- where the pop-ups appear
- the duration pop-ups stay visible
- their theme and
- opacity

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the `Run` window (or click `Run` in the main menu), type `xfce4-notifyd-config`, and hit enter to get the GUI and make your choice.

Alternatively, if you want to use the mouse, you'll have to do a bit of extra work to get `xfce4-notifyd-config` to appear as an option in `Main Menu`, `Preferences`:

- copy over `/usr/share/applications/xfce4-notifyd-config.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`
- open the copied file with Nano (or any other text editor)
- navigate to near the end of the file and look for the line `OnlyShowIn=XFCE`
- edit that line to read `OnlyShowIn=XFCE;LXDE`
- save the changes

You should now see `Notifications` in `Main Menu`, `Preferences`. Clicking on that will bring up the GUI (that could be also accessed by typing `xfce4-notifyd-config` in a terminal or in the dialog box obtained by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

Comment: it's smaller than the lubuntu's popup.

Comment: This was a super helpful answer! Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that `xfce4-notifyd` cannot control the notifications if `notify-osd` is also installed (true in 11.10 and still in 15.10). To fix this without re-login: `sudo apt-get remove notify-osd; sudo killall notify-osd`.

Answer (score 2):

Install `notifyosdconfig`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

Full Tutorial: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html

Screenshot

[image: From tutorial]

Comment: ... in my testing - this works in ubuntu but doesnt work in lubuntu :(  Can you confirm this?

Comment: Wow, that would be a drag if it does not work on Lubuntu, I am asking in #lubuntu

Comment: Ok I gave it a chance and it does not work @fossfreedom is right.

Comment: These install instructions do no longer work in Ubuntu 15.04 and up. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/648231) for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

By coincidence I discovered that `notifyosdconfig` works with `xfce4-notifyd`, 
but you have to remove `notify-osd` and the `notification-daemon`.
FYI: I'm on Lubuntu 12.10

Sorry: disregard my answer, turned out that it doesn't change the settings of xfce4-notifyd :-(

Comment: If it didn't work, you might consider deleting it.  Also, don't use bold for commands, whether its just names or not.

Comment: Yes, I too feel this answer may not be necessary since it specifies 12.10 and 12.10 doesn't need any fixes because the pop-ups are handled by xfce4-notifyd by default.